# What is equivalent of “failure” in german

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

I was trying to translate an English sentence to German, but I don’t know which word best fits to *failure* in the following context.

> The affective filter is a theoretical construct in second language acquisition that attempts to explain the emotional variables associated with the success or **failure of acquiring a second language.**

My translation attempt was:

> Der affektiver Filter ist ein theoretisches Konstrukt beim Zweitspracherwerb, das versucht, die mit dem Erfolg assoziierten, emotionalen Variablen oder das Versagen des Erwerbs einer Zweitsprache zu erklären.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Versagen" is maybe good enough and hasn't been a bad choice at all.

In a German sentence, it would probably be too unspecific, however. "Versagen" can - just like "failure" mean some*thing* or some*one* did not succeed (That means, it also covers the meaning of "Defekt").

Some*one* failing is best expressed using "Misserfolg" - The opposite of "Erfolg"

So your sentence could probably go like

> Der affektive Filter ist ein theoretisches Konstrukt, das versucht, die emotionalen Variablen zu erklären, die mit Erfolg oder Misserfolg beim Erwerb einer Zweitsprache verknüpft sind.

(I reckoned there was a redundant "Zweitsprachenerwerb" and removed it)

Comment: I've learnt two news things by your explanation. I'll trying to find out what antonyms of a word is, and associated with means "verknüpft mit".Thank you for the tips

Comment: *Misslingen* is also appropriate.

Comment: @Dragut assoziiert is perfectly fine, too

Answer (score 3):

> das Versagen des Erwerbs einer Zweitsprache

Hier passt auch Scheitern, aber dann *beim* Erwerb.

> das Scheitern beim Erwerb einer Zweitsprache

Comment: Obwohl ich auch der Meinung bin, dass _failure_ normalerweise am besten als _Versagen_ passt, glaube ich, dass in diesem speziellen Kontext _scheitern_ vielleicht noch besser ist.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Misslingen or Scheitern rather than Misserfolg, which seems like a bit less than a failure to my mind.